# Summing sub-lists of lists into a new list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Have a list where each element is a pair of properties of particles. Wanted to combine the values for the pairs into a new list. Know how to do this if each pair was a separate list but not entirely sure if their self-contained in another list.

```
list = [[[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0]], [[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9]]]
```

And so sort of output with

```
list2 = [[2116, -0.1831, -0.334, 424], [881.0, 0.259, -0.045, -811]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and the built-in functions [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
lst = [[[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0]],
        [[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9]]]

result = [[sum(e) for e in zip(*l)] for l in lst]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[2116.0, -0.1831, -0.33399999999999996, 424.0], [881.0, 0.2529, 0.044999999999999984, -811.1]]
```

The part:

```
zip(*l)
```

transforms (for example):

```
[[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0]]
```

into something like this:

```
[(846.0, 1270.0), (-0.0431, -0.14), (-0.16, -0.174), (-846.0, 1270.0)]
```

then `sum(e)` just sums the pairs.

Comment: oh great, thanks for explanation of the steps involved as well.

Answer (score 1):

With numpy in 1 line :

```
import numpy as np

original_list = np.array(
    [[[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0]],
     [[846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0], [35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9]]]
)

summed_list = np.array([np.sum(i, axis=0) for i in original_list])
```

I think it should be the shortest.